# Vmfs vmware esxi data recovery

Tags: vmware-esxi, data-recovery

One of our engineers noticed a missing vmdk file. It resided on a vmfs partition.

I was wondering is there any software to recover the missing vmdk that anyone can recommend using? Have searched the site but nothing stood out. The partitioning and raid all functional.

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: No backups of the VM and/or the VMDK?

Comment: foolishly not! :(

Comment: You could always just rewrite one yourself based on a similar one - they're just plain text and follow a very clear set of stanzas

Comment: Sorry @Chopper3 I don't understand?!

Comment: Sorry, misread the question, thought you'd lost your VM descriptor file - please ignore.

Comment: Ah - I thought you were suggesting building our own data recovery tools ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to ewwhite's comments -

Unfortunately I did not find a solution however giving the disks to a specialised data recovery center - they were able to recover the missing data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[UFS Explorer](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/download_pro.php) is the only tool I've used for VMFS filesystem recovery.

Comment: I tried this tool (after finding it elsewhere) didn't have any luck / not very intuitive to use. Know of any guides?

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: Only by giving the tower unit to a data recovery place - no idea what they did sorry!

Comment: Mark an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do the rescue. By default the vmdk is a non sparse file and it might be fully allocated at creation. This means that you have big chances that it is not fragmented.

Use a hex editor or disk editor to open the vmdk partition.
Search for something that I expect to be on that VMDK, then do a reverse search for the boot sector signature or MBR signature. From that I would take the first ***GB (the size of VMDK) and save them in a file.